# Batch script to convert a Subversion (SVN) symlink text file into NTFS symbolic link

Tags: windows, svn, unix, batch-file, symlink

**Our Setup:**
We are using a mix of Windows XP and Windows 7 machines for development, and some unix servers which hold our Subversion (SVN) repository and host our websites.
Our websites are stored in the SVN repo, and so when changes to the website need to be done, we check out a working copy of the SVN to our Windows machines. When all the changes are done, we commit the working copy back to the SVN repo, and a bash script deploys the head of the repo to the webservers. (pretty standard stuff)

**My Problem:** 
The website uses (unix) symbolic links (which cannot be replaced). So checking it out and committing from the unix server works fine and the symlinks survive. But since we are using Windows dev machines, SVN does not automatically convert their representation of symlinks to Windows/NTFS symlinks even though they are supported (our Windows XP machines have the relevant drivers installed).
SVN symlinks are files without extension which contain this:

```
link  /path/link/was/pointing/to
```

**My Questions:**
I'm not fluent in batch scripting (used to unix bash scripting). 
Any guidance on how to best convert SVN's text symlink to a working Windows/NTFS symlink in a batch script would be very well received.

What would happen if I commit a Windows symlink to the SVN repo? 
Would I need a second script which converts the Windows symlink back to a SVN text link?
Would the latter break the Unix side SVN text link to Unix symlink conversion?

Comment: Windows symbolic links do not work the same way as Unix ones. Also, you can't in any easy fashion create symbolic links in Windows from the command line, and I have never heard anything script-wise that can, considering those files are compiled automatically by Windows. And because of that, you can't really convert the other way around, because scripting languages typically don't support binary data.

Comment: You certainly can create symbolic links in Windows Vista and earlier, using only the command-line and built-in commands. Windows XP requires a separate (small) download, and only gives the equivalent of hard links. See [Complete Guide to Symbolic Links on Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend getting into VBScript and Windows Script Host. Say, I had a file called `C:\Temp\Hello.txt` and I wanted to create a link `C:\Temp\Sample`. I'll create a script named `MakeSample.vbs` as follows:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
Set oMyShortcut = WshShell.CreateShortcut("C:\Temp\Sample2.lnk")
oMyShortcut.WindowStyle = 3
oMyShortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Temp\Hello.txt"
oMyShortCut.Save
```

Reading a LINK file would be straightforward in VBScript, for example:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\linkfile.")
txt = f.ReadAll
f.Close
MsgBox txt
```

I think it should be relatively straightforward to hack something up using the above as a starting point.